# Ember : handling multiple events with {{action}} tag?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using Ember.js and I'm trying to have a div element with two different actions : one when mouse enter and one when mouse leave.
I tried to do :

```
<div {{action "stopInfo" on="mouseLeave"}} {{action "startInfo" on="mouseEnter"}}>
```

But it only trigger the first action (mouseleave).

Is there a way to have 2 actions on the same element ?
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per issue [#569](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/569) multiple action helpers for a tag is not supported. To handle multiple events you should use a custom `Ember.View` for that. In your case something like this, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/2V9cP/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
{{#view App.ActionView}}
    ... content of div ...
{{/view}}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.ActionView = Ember.View.extend({
    stopInfo: function(evt) { console.log('stop info'); },
    startInfo: function(evt) { console.log('start info'); },

    click: Ember.alias('stopInfo'),
    mouseLeave: Ember.aliasMethod('stopInfo'),

    mouseEnter: Ember.aliasMethod('startInfo')
});​
```

I've used the `Ember.alias` helper here, just to illustrate how I would use the same function for multiple view events ...

Comment: I think it should be `{{#view App.ActionView}}` with `#`.

Answer (score 10):

This will likely be supported in the next version of Ember (1.13). The PR that fixes it is here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11373

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now that ember is deprecating views.

Comment: The Ember js team did indeed fix this problem in 1.13; see #11373 at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v1.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) for that.

```
<button {{action (pipe addToCart purchase redirectToThankYouPage) item}}>
  1-Click Buy
</button>
```

or

```
<button {{action (queue (action "backupData") (action "unsafeOperation") (action "restoreBackup"))}} />
```