# Assign two actions to one element in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

`<span {{action 'toggleChildren' 'ServerObjects'}} {{action 'contextMenu' on='contextMenu'}}>{{server.name}}</span>`

Unfortunatelly when I add this second action, the first one stops working. I can't find a way to assign two actions to one element.

I found this topic: [Ember : handling multiple events with {{action}} tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544565/ember-handling-multiple-events-with-action-tag) . Does it still apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link no longer really applies - Views are being removed from Ember.

The way to do it is with a component for your span element:

**Handlebars**

```
{{my-span on-click=(action 'handleComponentSpanClick')
          on-context-menu=(action 'handleComponentSpanContextMenu')}}
```

**JavaScript**

```
App.MySpanComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  click: function(e) {
    this.attrs['on-click'](e);
  },
  contextMenu: function(e) {
    this.attrs['on-context-menu'](e);
  }
});
```

Ember recently came out with improved {{action}}'s which allow you to put actions directly on HTML elements - for example a `<span>`s `onclick`:

```
<span onclick={{action 'handleRegularSpanClick'}}
      oncontextmenu={{action 'handleRegularSpanContextMenu'}}>
  Regular Span
</span>
```

**JSBin**

http://jsbin.com/jaxico/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Nice, could you please point me to the webpage where this info can be found?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html and scroll to `Closure Actions`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the answer you're looking for. But I would just use one action which would handle this click and either call other actions via `this.send("actionName")` or other methods in your controller (or whereever you handle the actions).